# javascript extend an object not working

Tags: javascript

Banging my head against the wall and I know it's gotta be something stupid...

I have a basic comment(review)/voting system. I am pulling the reviews from the mongo db and in an asysnc.waterfall function, trying to add the votes to each review. Here is the function that adds the votes:

```
        function(reviews, callback) {
            let newReviews = [];
            _.forEach(reviews, function(review,idx) {
                Vote.find({review:review._id}).exec(function(err1, votes){
                    if (err1){
                        callback(err1,null);
                    }else{
                        console.log("1: REVIEW - ", review);
                        review.votes = votes;
                        console.log("2: VOTES - ", review.votes);
                        newReviews.push(review);
                        console.log("3: REVIEW - ", review);
                        if( newReviews.length == reviews.length ){
                            callback(null,newReviews);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

The votes item never gets populated even though there's data there. Here's some output from those logging statements:

```
1: REVIEW -  { _id: 5a2086139c3c077e546622,
  user:
   { passProfileImageURL: '/modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png',
     _id: 5a15cd47b9fd942e50e5b,
     provider: 'local',
     username: 'xxx',
     profileImageURL: '/modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png' },
  beach:
   { _id: 57995db6666f1ec6f3750,
     slug: 'carmel-city-beach-carmel-by-the-sea-california-united-states',
     Name: 'Carmel City Beach' },
  totalVotes: 1,
  reports:
   [ { _id: 5a2087f672107f48dd4ed,
       user: 5a15cd47db50942e50e5b,
       review: 5a208639c3c077e546622,
       __v: 0,
       updated: 2017-11-30T22:36:38.598Z,
       created: 2017-11-30T22:36:38.598Z } ],
  created: 2017-11-30T22:30:14.276Z,
  comment: 'Why am i doing this???',
  rating: 3 }
2: VOTES -  [ { _id: 5a26fab26a6f85b39484,
    review: 5a20867c3c077e546622,
    Type: 'review',
    user: 5a15cd4db50942e50e5b,
    __v: 0,
    updated: 2017-12-05T19:59:46.318Z,
    created: 2017-12-05T19:59:46.318Z,
    IsVote: true } ]
3: REVIEW -  { _id: 5a208676139c3c077e546622,
  user:
   { passProfileImageURL: '/modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png',
     _id: 5a15cd47b50942e50e5b,
     provider: 'local',
     username: 'mit',
     profileImageURL: '/modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png' },
  beach:
   { _id: 579db6666fcec6f3750,
     slug: 'carmel-city',
     Name: 'Carmel City' },
  totalVotes: 1,
  reports:
   [ { _id: 5a2087b107f48dd4ed,
       user: 5a15cfdb50942e50e5b,
       review: 5a208673c077e546622,
       __v: 0,
       updated: 2017-11-30T22:36:38.598Z,
       created: 2017-11-30T22:36:38.598Z } ],
  created: 2017-11-30T22:30:14.276Z,
  comment: 'Why am i doing this???',
  rating: 3 }
```

Doesn't make sense that the number 2 item would log correctly, but 3 does not...can anyone help me make sense of this stupid issue? Or is it just me? LOL

As requested, here's the Vote mongoose schema definition:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var config = {

Type: {
    type: String
},

IsVote: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
},

created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},

updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},

owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
},

user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},

review: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Review'
}

};

var VoteSchema = new Schema(config, {
    collection: 'votes'
});

/**
 * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
 */
VoteSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    next();
});

VoteSchema.method('toggleVote', function() {
    this.IsVote = !this.IsVote;
    return this.save();
});

VoteSchema.static('createFromReview', function(reviewId, user) {
    return new this({
        review: reviewId,
        Type: 'review',
        user: user
    });
});


mongoose.model('Vote', VoteSchema);
```

Comment: Can you please post a copy of your `Vote` Mongoose schema?

Comment: @Pytth - edited as requested. Thank you